# Posts don't appear on Template Page

Tags: posts, page-template, html

I made a Template page `galerie.php` and I wanted to show posts there.

Why isn't this working? It seems that posts only appear at `home page` for some reason.

The code is:

```
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post() ?>
      <div id="owl-images" class="owl-carousel">
        <a href="<?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="<?php the_title() ?>">
          <div class="item">
            <div class="lazyOwl" style="background:url("<?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>") no-repeat center center;background-size:cover;height:300px;" alt=""></div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Have you set this as a page template for any page? I don't think while(have_posts()) : the_post() will work for custom page templates.

Comment: No I didn't because I have different pages with different contents.

Comment: what posts would you like to show in this template?

Comment: Please read about WP_Query http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 0):

1 Go to your WordPress Administration Panel.
2 edit home page
3 select template and update
4 go to setting-> reading , select home page

Answer (score 0):

You can add after while loop reset & query_posts() same as: `wp_reset_query(); query_posts('post_type=&showposts=10');`